# Two y-axis plot without overlapping

Tags: r, graphics

I am trying to make a graphic with to y-axis that the values of each y-axis start at the middle of the box so the 2 lines that I am plotting do not overlap. I have search for some time but have not found any way to do that with the basic X-Y graphics from R and i am adding some other things to the graphic so i don't want to do it with other package.

[image]

With the graphic in mind what I need it that the top one "merges" with the bottom and that the values on the left y-axis of the top graph change to the right but start at the middle, that way the lines wont overlap.

Comment: is this a scatter plot? you can probably just drop the `par(new=TRUE)` and change the `plot` under that to `points` (unless the scaling is different I guess)

Comment: No it is not a sactterplot it is a line plot with two series

Comment: What do you mean, that the lines should both start in the middle of the box? Do you mean the middle of the x axis, or the yaxis? Do you mean that one should start at the bottom/ left, and the other at the middle?

Comment: I mean that I want that the right and left y-axis start at a different height, that way the blue line and the black wont overlap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
d1 <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=sin(1:10))
d2 <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=sin(1:10)+10)

plot(rbind(d1,d2), t="n", yaxt="n")
lines(d1)
lines(d2)
axis(2, at=pretty(d1$y))
axis(4, at=pretty(d2$y))
```

Comment: Thanks baptiste that is what I want, but i have just a little problem and it is that the space between the two lines is kind of big. Is there a way to make it smaller? because cant appreciate the big jumps of it

Comment: you probably sh/could offset the data, and apply the opposite offset to the corresponding axis labels

Comment: Can you help me because i don't even know whats is and how to offset the data

Comment: people are more likely to help if you produce a minimal reproducible self-contained example